# Action not happening every certain amount of ticks

Tags: netlogo

this code is for the reproduction of an animal. It should happen every 10 ticks, but it is happening instantly and i dont know why.  They also have energy. Reproduction is set to be random to show females.

thanks in advance for the help.

```
turtles-own[ energia edad]
breed[perros perro]
to setup  
   resize-world 0 80 0 60
  clear-all
  ask patches[
    set pcolor green]

    create-perros 50
 [     
    set size 3        ;; easier to see
    set color yellow
setxy (41 + random 39) random 60
    set heading random 360
    set energia 100
    set edad 1
  ]
  
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  
  ask perros [ set edad edad + 1]
  
  ask perros [
    morir-perros
        moverse-perros
    reproducirse
      ]
  tick
end 
  to morir-perros
  
  if edad > 15 [die]
  if energia < 1 [die]
  
end


to moverse-perros
 
   set heading random 360 fd 5
  set energia energia - 5
 
end 
  
 to reproducirse 
  
  if ticks mod 10 = 0 [ if random 100 > 50 [set energia energia - 60
      hatch 1 [ rt random-float 360 fd 2
      set energia (energia + 60) / 3]]]
  
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you have `tick` to increment your time step at the end of your `go` procedure. In any model, `ticks` start at 0 by default, so your model is evaluating `ticks` mod 10:

```
observer> show 0 mod 10
observer: 0
```

Since that would satisfy the condition in `reproducirse`, the code is evaluated. You can handle this in a variety of ways. The simplest may be to modify your `if` statement in `reproducirse`- for example:

```
to reproducirse 
  if ticks > 0 and ticks mod 10 = 0 [ if random 100 > 50 [set energia energia - 60
    hatch 1 [ rt random-float 360 fd 2
      set energia (energia + 60) / 3]]]
end
```

Comment: Luke, Thanks for answering! That was and easy fix, I didnt realize thank you so much.

Comment: @bksnlow - No problem, glad that sorted you out. If this question has been completely resolved, can you please click the little checkmark next to this answer to mark the answer as accepted and the question as closed?